# react limit number of selection

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

I am new to React and would need help to limit the number of selected items from a dropdown menu. My dropdown has over 15 options, but I want the user to be able to select a maximum of 5 items.
I found different ways of doing it using JQuery but I cannot implement them with React. 
Thanks for your help!

Edit: I am using a component from Semantic UI for the dropdown:

```
handleSelectTag = (event, data) => {
this.setState({ selectedTagsId: data.value })
}   

const tagOptions = this.state.existingTags.map(tag => {
  return {key: tag.id, text: tag.name, value: tag.id}
})

<Dropdown placeholder='Tags' fluid multiple selection options={tagOptions} onChange={this.handleSelectTag} />
```

Comment: can you link the code that implements your dropdown ?

Comment: I'm using a component from Semantic UI. Just edited my question with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add a simple conditional on the `handleSelectTag()` method to check the length of how many tags you've selected. If the user has selected too many, just call an `alert()` for now, or poke around for what behavior you want to happen after the user has selected 5. Maybe something like the below to start..

```
// assuming this.state.selectedTagsId is an array
handleSelectTag = (event, data) => {
  if (this.state.selectedTagsId.length > 5) {
    alert('You may only select 5');
  }
  else {
    this.setState({ selectedTagsId: data.value }) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher! I will go with this solution for now